# Why are the forward/back keyboard shortcuts in Google Calendar reversed?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-calendar

I recently started using Google Calendar a lot more, and one of the first things I did was look for keyboard shortcuts to speed up my planning. I found this:

[image: k is back, j is forward]

I'm wondering whether there's some motivation behind choosing those particular shortcuts, because intuitively, I would expect <kbd>j</kbd> to go back and <kbd>k</kbd> to go forward, given that <kbd>k</kbd> is on the right.

Comment: That would also make sense because in Gmail j navigates to an older conversation and k navigates to a newer conversation.  Just figure out a simple way to remember which ones are for which when switching between Gmail and Google Calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> keys come from the [Vi text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) and ADM3A computer terminals, where they originally were used for *vertical* navigation – they mean "cursor down" and "cursor up" respectively. See [HJKL keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys#HJKL_keys) for the full set.

(Nowadays you'll also find these hidden hotkeys in various other webapps, such as Twitter timelines or Ars Technica comment threads.)

Because <kbd>j</kbd> moves the cursor down in this keymap, it makes sense for it to scroll down to the next item – and it used to be an obvious choice in earlier Google Calendar UI versions, which used vertical scrolling for the month view. (If I remember correctly, that is.)

The only problem is that the "Material 2" redesign for Google Calendar switched to sideways scrolling for months, which no longer matches the hotkey choice. *(And, IMHO, is completely unintuitive for a calendar in general – even when I'm swiping left/right on the Android app.)*